# Merging two tables in Pandas, and adding in multiple Indices too

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have data that's to be analysed for a project I'm working in,  mostly done using pandas at the moment as the data comes in from Excel.

I'm trying to merge some of these tables, based on a column, which isn't the issue, the issue is that the tables have column names that are the same, looking kind of like below:

[image]

the columns that get reused are 10-30, 30-50 etc.

I want to do it so that i can have a higher index on the numbered columns, and have it called something like "Percentages", "Real miles" etc, so that when I'm completing calculations later on it's easier to link up the relevant cells, as well as have it more presentable at the end

Right now I'm having difficulty producing this, as the only place I've seen that have something more akin to what I want is when you see people creating dataframes from tuple/dictionaries, but considering how large the final inputs will be in this project, I wouldn't know how to go about writing them in.

I'm basically looking to have it look like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your issue

Using the Merge function you can set suffix for each of the columns from each of the dataframes. E.g.:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey',suffixes=('_left', '_right'))
```

This way you will differentiate between columns coming from each of your dataframes.

Comment: hi man, thanks for your reply, it's not quite what i'm looking for. in the help page for pandas there is a way of setting a dataframe that has multiple laters to it, here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index if you look at the example near the end, i'm looking to have those multiple layers on the index, but with an existing dataframe, but all their examples are done using tuples, not an existing dataframe